# HBase fails to start master (can't connect to zookeeper)

Tags: hbase

i'm using hbase on a local machine and run it in standalone mode (so not distribuited or pseudo-d. mode) but when i try to start hbase after few seconds crashes because it can't start correctly zookeeper.

i downloaded this version of hbase : [hbase](http://it.apache.contactlab.it/hbase/stable/)
did the untar and started with ./start-hbase.sh (after the configuration)

this is the log : [log hbase](http://pastebin.com/2XendXwm)

then in **hbase-site.xml** i have :

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/raff0z/Scaricati/hbase/hbDATA/</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

in **hbase-env.sh** there is :

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

Comment: solved, it was a java update -.-

Comment: I think you should close the question or something